# Generalizing the Chinese remainder theorem with fibred products

Tags: commutative-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem, fibre-product

For a commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I,J\subset R$ with $I+J$ we have an isomorphism
$$R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I\times R/J.$$
But I'm wondering how much can be said if $I+J\neq R$. We still have an injection
$$R/(I\cap J)\ \hookrightarrow\ R/I\times R/J,$$
but this is not surjective in general. In fact we even have an injection into the fibred product
$$R/(I\cap J)\ \hookrightarrow\ R/I\times_{R/(I+J)}R/J,$$
which is the usual Cartesian product if $I+J=R$. My question is whether this latter map *is* surjective in general? For the few simple examples I checked it is indeed surjective. However, my failed attempts at proving this seem to suggest that it isn't surjective, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for the link! I searched the site but didn't find my question. Should I delete this question now, or leave it up to increase the chances of it being found in the future?